# What value does the empty statement evaluate to?

Tags: javascript, undefined, evaluation

My *very* fine question is: in JavaScript, what value does the empty statement evaluate to?

This is the empty statement:

`;`

...and if I evaluate it, I get `undefined`.

```js
console.log(eval(';')) // 'undefined'
```

However, here is another empty statement (after a statement containing a number literal):

`1;;`

...and yet this appears to evaluate to `1`.

```js
console.log(eval('1;;')) // '1'
```

Which surprises me.

So, what does the empty statement evaluate to?

I note the [spec says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-empty-statement) the empty statement returns "`empty`". I don't know what that means yet.

The [spec also says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values):

> When the term “empty” is used as if it was naming a value, it is
> equivalent to saying “no value of any type”.

So, the empty statement returns "no value of any type". That means it cannot return `undefined` (which is a value of type `Undefined`). I am unsure how this maps to userland code.

Comment: `1;;` contains an empty statement.

Comment: What even is the question here? Does *it* evaluate to *something* - as you have run the code you already know the answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX Please explain.

Comment: The semicolon delineates a statement. So the first statement is `1;` (which trivially evaluates to `1`). The second is `;`?

Comment: One semicolon doesn't create e statement. Semicolons are more like separators than statement creators.

Comment: [empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty)

Comment: @JaromandaX `1;;` is two statements, the first is `1;` the second is `;` (an empty statement). `;;` is two empty statements. There is not "automatic semicolon removal" as a counterpart to automatic semicolon insertion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [empty statement](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-EmptyStatement) returns nothing at all ([*empty*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation): "no value of any type"). A [statement list](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-StatementList), like the one in the body of a [Script](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-scripts) that `eval` is parsing the code as, [returns the value of the last statement that did return anything](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> The value of a StatementList is the value of the last value-producing
> item in the StatementList. For example, the following calls to the
> eval function all return the value 1:
>
> ```
> eval("1;;;;;")
> eval("1;{}")
> eval("1;var a;")
> ```

An empty statement list, empty script, empty block, or statement list containing no value-producing statements evaluates to *empty*.

The [*PerformEval* operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performeval) then converts that *empty* value to `undefined` in step 30:

> If *result*.[[Type]] is `normal` and *result*.[[Value]] is `empty`, then
>   Set *result* to NormalCompletion(`undefined`).